# how to increase the speed of R CMD build when directory contains large unassociated files?

Tags: r, build, performance, package

I have a R package in the directory ~/package; I also keep the output from my use of the package in the directory ~/package/out. When the content of ~/package/out gets very large, it takes minutes instead of seconds to build this package. Is there a way to have "R CMD build package" ignore the ~/package/out directory?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are a little short on details about what is in there --- but `R CMD` respects `.Rbuildignore`.

Here is a real example:

```
edd@max:~$ cat svn/rinside/pkg/.Rbuildignore 
inst/doc/html
inst/doc/latex
inst/doc/man
inst/doc
inst/lib
edd@max:~$
```

which tells `R CMD build` to ignore the doxygen=-generated documentation, as well as a library directory.

Comment: Second place is the first loser (or that's what my mother said).

Comment: Thanks for the example - I just put "out" in the file, and also found that out/*Rdata works as well. although, notably, if it was "out/" or "*Rdata", I got an error "Quantifier follows nothing in regex.

Answer (score 3):

See the documentation on the .Rbuildignore file in [building packages](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Building-packages) section of the R-Extensions manual.